# Idiomatic expression for "close to the average, yet not the average"

Tags: phrase-request

What's the idiomatic way of describing someone's ability level as being very-very close to the average, yet not the average? For example,

> Jack's reading ability is **one fraction of a millimeter** below average.

Comment: *Just below average*.

Comment: Reading tests are not exact enough for the kind of precision you ask for.

Comment: Just below, as already suggested, or a tad below, a bit below, a little below, a hair below, etc.

Comment: You don't measure reading ability in terms of distance. So, that sentence would be figurative at best and confusing at worst.

Comment: A reasonably "honest" euphemism would be [*His  reading ability **is slightly below par.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+slightly+below+par%22) About 10% of those 700+ written instances are immediately followed by ***....but***, which suggests it's often used in contexts where the writer/speaker is trying to downplay the almost inevitable negative connotations of "below average".

Comment: @JasonBassford - I gave that sentence as a kind of template. I didn't mean to present "one fraction of a millimeter" as one of the possible idiomatic phrases.

Answer (score 1):

If actual units are not available, the easiest way is to use an adverb to modify "below"

> just below average
>   slightly below average

Or a "fake" unit:

> a tad below average
>   a bit below average
>   a hairbreadth below average

But in the context given (reading tests) the test is not that accurate. So you can just say>

> about average
>   very close to average